# Use Frama-c to analyze a project with CMake build infrastructure

Tags: c, cmake, frama-c, value-analysis

I need to use frama-c value analysis plug-in to analyze some projects. These projects use CMake build infrastructure as their build system.

I have used frama-c to analyze each file separately. This way, the information about the entry point will be lost. More precisely, frama-c requires an entry point for the files that do not include a "main" function and therefore it is challenging to cover all functions and choose the best entry point within a single file from the project.

My question is that is there a way that we can run frama-c on the entire project as a whole unit (not file by file)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Frama-C accepts multiple files on its command-line. This will work if the configuration of the preprocessor (option `-cpp-extra-args`, used in particular for includes) is the same accross all files.

If you need different preprocessor settings for different files, you should preprocess each file alone (only `cpp`, no Frama-C), and save each result as a `.i` file. Then, you can supply all those preprocessed files to Frama-C simultaneously. Usually, the first operation can be done by tweaking the build process.

Comment: Thanks for your great solution, it worked! I just have a question about saving the preprocessed file. When I use the command "frama-c -cpp-command 'gcc -C -E -I. -o %2 %1' small.c small.i", frama-c complains that small.i does not exist and considers it as another input, not the output file name! For now I was able to get the preprocessed result using -print option, but that prints some extra kernel messages as well, which is not as desirable. What is your suggestion for saving .i file? Thanks! @byako

Comment: @MehrnooshEP you don't have to provide the name of the intermediate `.i` file in this setting, frama-c will take care of that itself. It is only if you choose to pre-process a C file outside of frama-c that you need to save a `.i` file and give it as input to Frama-C. In other word, you can do either `frama-c -cpp-command bla file.c` or `cpp -o file.i file.c && frama-c file.i`, but **not** `frama-c -cpp-command bla file.c file.i`

Comment: @Virgile I see, I was mixing the two! Thanks for the explanation.